# How do I use SVC in scikit learn if a feature is text summary?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My question is if there are 6 features in a dataset, if some feature are non-numeric, I can convert them via label encoder or other methods. But if one of the feature is a huge text body (a paragraph), what pre-processing techniques should I be using to use to to model a SVC or KNN classifier (and not Naive Bayes) ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any plan to pre-process the "huge text body" with some language-corpus based tools ( alike NLTK ) so as to distill some feature-engineering outputs?

Comment: Yes and find a bad of words, topics etc.But I am confused on how to link the other 5 features with this NLP-ized 6 feature so that I can use it in SVC or KNN.

Comment: The case seems to me to be the very opposite one, you have to design and process new, NLP-based, features, that will together, with those ready, enter into a `scikit-learn` SVC-classifier training/cross-validation setup.

Comment: The original 5 + 1 features might become 5 + features postNLP. Got it ! thanks.

Comment: Right, that is the classical scenario, as you may get more NLP-metrics to get the free-text annotations reasonably analysed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CountVectorizer or TfidfVectorizer, which are standard methods for text feature extraction. You can find the [documentation here](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction), and a [comprehensive tutorial on working with text data here](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html).